# CXXRecords getNameAsString, how to get full name?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, libtooling

```
 namespace A {
     namespace B {
         class C {
             class D {
             };
         };
     }
 }
```

`CXXRecords` for `D` with `getNameAsString` would return `D`.
How can I get the fullname `::A::B::C::D` ?

I tried to recursively call `getParent` but I couldn't get the namespaces..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of searching and trying i found

```
QualType::getAsString(cl->getASTContext().getTypeDeclType(const_cast<CXXRecordDecl*>(cl)).split())
```

As useable solution, it will output `class A::B::C::D`.
For `namespace using std; vector<int> g;` it will output `class std::vector<int>`.

Having only `std::vector` would be nice, but
simple string manipulation will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your RecordDecl pointer variable is named recordDecl, you can simply use 
`recordDecl->getQualifiedNameAsString()`