How to get the complete type as string with namespace info (if any) from the Decl/ParmDecl
I am trying to extract all the function signatures, essentially parameters complete type, with namespace from a c/cpp source. The objective is to create a file in which I can decleare the same type variable, without opening the namespace in which they are and to be able to compile that file successfully.
I've objects of Type* from ParamVarDecl* using RecursiveASTVisitor, in very simple cases I can get the type as string, which is fine but in this case-
//signature.cpp
//#includes...

using namespace std;

    void func(size_t pin) {
        //some def.
    }

dumping Type* obtained from, paramDecl->getType().getTypePtrOrNull()
I get the AST as,
ElaboratedType 0x1c06b378df0 'size_t' sugar
`-TypedefType 0x1c06b378dc0 'size_t' sugar
  |-Typedef 0x1c06b378b28 'size_t'
  `-BuiltinType 0x1c0698845e0 'unsigned long long'

In this AST there is no info of std::, How do I get this info?
I can extract 'unsigned long long' and use that, but I am specifically looking for a way to get the namspaces in such cases.
Many thanks.

unsingend long long is in no namespace

Are you expecting to see std::size_t? If so remove using namespace std; this way it will find the size_t in global namespace

but "size_t" is in "std" right? actually I want that info, so that I can decleare it in another file as std::size_t.

It is also available in the global namespace, you just showed yourself why the recommendation is to never use using namespace std;

Actually, the source file is not mine to change the code. I am writing a tool in which can handle such cases.

Then I would say your tool is correct (and the source file maybe not). It does find the size_t type (alias) the code actually will use.

yes :), but in the file where I want to re-decleare it, I don't want to open any namespaces, thats why I need to know about "std::" as well, so That I can decleare it like "std::size_t"

For each type T from the Standard C library, the types ::T and std::T are reserved to the implementation and, when defined, ::T shall be identical to std::T. So it you want to achieve that instead of size_t your tool says std::size_t then code it.

Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701536/cxxrecords-getnameasstring-how-to-get-full-name and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812221/print-a-fully-qualified-type-of-a-parameter-parmvardecl-or-a-field-fielddecl .  Do one of those work?  If not, could you clarify by specifying what requirements they do not meet?

There are two typedefs:  using ::size_t = unsigned long long; and using ::std::size_t = unsigned long long;.  Your code is preferentially using the ::size_t, because that's how the code is written.

@ScottMcPeak Those solutions are working for most cases, but specifically in this case it shows no ::std

@BitKnight what the comments are trying to get at is that size_t is plausibly the right answer. Both size_t and std::size_t are typedefs in C++. The question doesn't provide enough information to be sure that size_t is not the name found by unqualified name lookup.

Thanks for valuable comments. I can use size_t instead of std::size_t to decleare it in another file, since both size_t and std::size_t are typedefs in C++.
